# Why is the <center> tag deprecated in HTML?

Tags: html, tags, center, deprecated

I am just curious as to why the `<center>` tag in HTML was deprecated.

The `<center>` was a simple way of quickly center-aligning blocks of text and images by encapsulating the container in a `<center>` tag, and I really cannot find any simpler way on how to do it now.

Anyone know of any simple way on how to center "stuff" (not the `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` and width thing), something that replaces `<center>` ?  And also, why was it deprecated?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

The `<center>` element was deprecated because it defines the *presentation* of its contents — it does not describe its contents.

One method of centering is to set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties of the element to `auto`, and then set the parent element’s `text-align` property to `center`. This guarantees that the element will be centered in all modern browsers.

Comment: Yes, CSS is all about spliting presentation and data.

Comment: Ivan, CSS is all about presentation; it is not about splitting - as the inline style attributes in some answers here demonstrate! It is of course a very good idea to use sensible classes and not inline CSS, but that is a distinct concept to using CSS for presentation.

Comment: I've had some cases (which I can't recall atm) where setting both the `margin` and `text-align` did not center my element in IE, but wrapping it with `<center>` did work... I'll try to find an example.

Comment: fudgey, use a DOCTYPE and write valid code, and you will get *nearly* compliant behaviour from IE. Still far from perfect, but using a DOCTYPE is the vital first step to avoiding browser quirks.

Comment: the auto margin trick only works for block level elements. use `display: block;` on an inline element.

Comment: I'm sure the seventeen nested divs on a typical WP or Drupal template really help to separate out the presentation details :P </troll> ( <- look, semantic tag!)

Comment: Does the `margin` have to be `0 auto`?  I've tried just `auto` on a `pre` element, and it works the same in Gecko as `0 auto`, or when the `div` has `text-align: -moz-center` instead of `text-align: center`, or when the `div` used to be `center`.  What's the point of `0`?  Why not just `auto`?

Comment: `auto` is fine. `0 auto` sets the top/bottom to `0` and left/right to `auto`.

Comment: This only works when your `div` has a defined and previously known width.

Comment: Note that `0 auto` also sets the margin for top & bottom to 0 - which has nothing to do with the current problem. A better solution is to set `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto` which is a bit longer but more correct.

Comment: Everyone talking about structure and presentation. But, why <p> is not deprecated? that tag has the same purpose about presentation in HTML.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique: <p> denotes a paragraph of text, which is what it *is*, not how it is presented. Just because browsers make <p> a block element with top and bottom margins by default doesn't make it presentational in nature.

Comment: @JordanRyanMoore you said: "not how it is presented".. Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each <p> element. The margins can be modified with CSS (with the margin properties). source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_p.asp)

Comment: @EleazarEnrique - That was brave of you to cite W3Schools here! The best way to deal with browsers doing WTF ever they feel like doing with <p> tags etc. is to use a reset.css like [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) wrote

Comment: What about `<div>` and `<span>` ? They define the layout and don't describe it's contents.

Comment: @ChrisSmith, they are still "semantatic" elements, in that they define (topological) *structures* in the page, not looks (unlike CENTER).

Comment: `<center>` is an important tag, and there is a high chance it won't be removed. Many websites still use it, like Google.

Answer (score 43):

### The Least Popular Answer

1. A deprecated tag is not necessarily a *bad* tag;
2. There *are* tags that deal with presentation logic, `center` is one of them;
3. A `center` tag is not the same as a div with `text-align:center`;
4. The fact that you have *another* way to do something doesn't make it invalid.

**Let me explain** because there are notorious downvoters here who will think I'm defending oldschool HTML4 or something. No I'm not. But the debate around `center` is simply a trend war, there is no real reason to ditch a tag that serves a valid purpose well.

So let's see the major arguments against it.

- ***"It describes presentation, not semantics!"***
  No. It describes a logical arrangement - and yes, it has a default appearance, just as other tags like `<p>` or `<ul>` do. But the point is the enclosed part's relation to its surroundings. Center says "this is something we separate by
  visually different positioning".
- ***"It's not valid"***
  Yes it is. It's just deprecated, as in, *could be removed later*. For 15+ years now. And it's not going anywhere, apparently. There are major sites (including google.com) that use this tag because it's very readable and to the point - and those are the same reasons we like HTML5 tags for.
- ***"It's not supported in HTML5"***
  It's one of the most [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=center) tags, actually. MDN says "its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time" - good point, but *that day may never come*, to quote a classic. Center was already deprecated in like 2004 or so - it's still here and still useful.
- ***"It's oldschool"***
  Shoelaces are oldschool too. New methods don't invalidate the old. You want to feel progressive and modern: fine. But don't make it the law.
- ***"It's stupid / awkward / lame / tells a story about you"***
  None of these. It's like a hammer: one tool for a specific job. There are other tools for the same job and other jobs for the same tool; but it was created to solve a certain problem and that problem is still around so we might as well just use a dedicated solution.
- ***"You shouldn't do this, because, CSS"***
  Centering can absolutely be achieved by CSS but that's just one way, not the only one, let alone the only *appropriate* one. Anything that's *supported, working and readable* should be ok to use. Also, the same argument happened before flexboxes and CSS grids, which is funny because back then there was no CSS way to achieve what center did. No, `text-align:center` is not the same. No, `margin:auto` is not the same. Anyone who argued against center tags before flexbox simply didn't know enough about CSS.

#### TL;DR:

> The only reason not to use `<center>` is because people will hate you.

Comment: The best answer I have read in this question. For the record I will continue to use <center>.

Comment: Yep, I was surprised to see it but Google is still using it on its home page in 2021.

Comment: Your IDE will also hate you... but that's not gonna stop me!

Comment: Aaaand I didn't mention emails. Certainly a bigger can of worms btw, so let's not go back to the days when we made webpages like we make emails today 

Comment: it's not just the best answer to this question.  It's one of the best answers written on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 24):

I still use the <center> tag sometimes because nothing in CSS works as well. Examples of trying to use a <div> trick and failing despite the [W3C claimed `<div>` equivalent for `<center>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER):

> The `CENTER` element is exactly equivalent to specifying the [`DIV`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#edef-DIV) element with the [`align`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-align) attribute set to `"center"`. The [`CENTER`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER) element is [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html#deprecated).

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">This div is centered, but it's a simple example.</div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: center;"><table border="1"><tr><td>&lt;div style="text-align: center;"&gt; didn't center correctly.</td></tr></table></div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"><table border="1"><tr><td>&lt;div style="text-align: center;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"&gt; still didn't center either</td></tr></table></div>
<br />
<center><table border="1"><tr><td>Actually Centered with &lt;center&gt; tag</td></tr></table></center>
<br />
<div align="center;"><table border="1"><tr><td>&lt;div align="center;"&gt;, which according to w3c is equivalent, didn't center correctly.</td></tr></table></div>
```

<center> gets results. To use CSS instead, you sometimes have to put CSS in several places and mess with it to get it to center right. To answer your question, **CSS has become a religion with believers and followers who shunned <center> <b> <i> <u> as blasphemy, unholy, and much too simple for the sake of their own job security.** And if they try to take your <table> away from you, ask them what the CSS equivalent of the colspan or rowspan attribute is.
*It is not the abstract or bookish truth, but the lived truth that counts.*
-- Zen

Comment: You also could use `display:flex; justify-content:center; text-align:center`

Comment: Note that in the third example, you set `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` in the wrapper `<div>`, but those styles should be set in the element to be centered (i.e. the `<table>`) instead. Indeed, with that change, the third example does center the table correctly. That said, this type of fragility/complexity does illustrate how the CSS way to center is less usable than the plain old `<center>` tag.

Comment: Dear prospective employer: If you're reading this because you Googled my name, please understand that I wrote this answer in 2018.

Answer (score 17):

According to [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_center.asp),

> The center element was deprecated in HTML 4.01, and is not supported in XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD.

The [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-CENTER) gives this reason for deprecating the tag:

> The CENTER element is exactly equivalent to specifying the DIV element with the align attribute set to "center".

Comment: I *so* wish this was actually true.

Comment: This is actually true, but DIV's align atribute is also deprecated :D

Comment: Note that it's not equivalent to `text-align: center`, though.  In Gecko, the `center` element is equivalent to a `div` element with the `style` attribute of `text-align: -moz-center;`.  Heh, so much for interoperability!

Comment: Note that w3schools is *not* W3C.

Comment: "The CENTER element is exactly equivalent to specifying the DIV element with the align attribute set to "center"." except it is clear by looking at the tag that it is centered. If this was a valid reason, we could depricate <strong>, <b>, all <h> and other tags and say they do the same thing as <span> with some css. besides, XHTML doesn't even recognize HTML5 tags such as canvas. It is only deprecated because of  the war against marquees, centers, tables, frame which is purely religious, as they all have a place.

Comment: @Dmitry <strong> and <h>'s have semantic meaning that goes beyond visual styling. I guess if <center> was still around you could style it with CSS, eg to make its content left justified.

Comment: @NickRice, good point. I'd been certainly in a pro-CENTER mood today until I saw your comment. :) I'm still sure something between that and the dreadful alternatives is badly missing from the spec. Why can't there be a `horizontal-align: center` attribute, for instance?

Comment: Best answer for me! There is one reason for me to not use <center> any more (for new stuff): You could not reset/revert the effect with CSS (so no media-query possible, etc.) But I have more then 500 mask with <center> in my project and to change that is a big job. May I will decide not to change them!

Answer (score 16):

What I do is take common tasks like centering or floating and make CSS classes out of them. When I do that I can use them throughout any of the pages. I can also call as many as I want on the same element.

```
.text_center {text-align: center;}
.center {margin: auto 0px;}
.float_left {float: left;}
```

Now I can use them in my HTML code to perform simple tasks.

```
<p class="text_center">Some Text</p>
```

Comment: That does not the same as <center>! (If someone like to replace center, that does not fit)

Answer (score 12):

You can still use this with [XHTML 1.0 Transitional](http://www.december.com/html/x1tran/) and [HTML 4.01 Transitional](http://www.december.com/html/4loose/) if you like. The only other way (best way, in my opinion) is with margins:

```
<div style="width:200px;margin:auto;">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Your HTML should define the element, not govern its presentation.

Answer (score 8):

HTML is intended for structuring data, not controlling layout. CSS is intended to control layout. You'll also find that many designers frown on using `<table>` for layouts for this very same reason.

Comment: I wish HTML was solely for structuring data... but it isn't. How often have you had to modify HTML before adding in some CSS? (Always for me). Nowadays, we use tools like React to separate data (and logic) from the layout/styling, and many now end up using JSX for layout/styling purposes (e.g. custom "Center" component). We've gone full circle.

Answer (score 8):

It's intended that markup, i.e. the HTML tags, represent meaning and structure, not appearance. It was badly mixed up in early versions of HTML but the standards people are trying to clean that up now.

One problem with letting tags control appearance is that your pages don't play well with devices for the handicapped, such as screen readers. It also leads to having lots and lots of tags in your text that don't help clarify the meaning, but rather clutter it with information of a different level.

So CSS was thought up to move formatting/display to a different language, which is separate from the text and can easily be kept that way. Among other things, this allows switching stylesheets to change the appearance of a Web page without touching the other markup. And to be able to do that for lots of pages in one swell foop.

The tools CSS gives you to do this are not always elegant, I'm on your side there. For instance, there is no way to do effective vertical centering. And horizontal centering, if it's not just text amenable to `text-align`, is not much better.

You have the choice of doing easy, effective and muddled or clean, elegant and cumbersome. I don't understand why Web developers put up with this mess, but I guess they're happy to have at least a chance to get their stuff done.

Comment: +1: As someone who's not even a web developer, I recognize how cumbersome it can be to specify certain presentational attributes using CSS. I still find it better to use CSS than muddling the structural markup, but... WTF? Who's in charge of defining that CSS spec, random monkeys they found in some remote jungle? Seriously.

Comment: Please, don't insult random monkeys in remote jungles!

Answer (score 7):

For text and images you can use `text-align`:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    I'm centered.
</div>
```

Comment: These are called inline elements.

Comment: Your solution does not work for <form...>

Answer (score 6):

You can add this to your css and use `<div class="center"></div>`

```
.center{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

or if you want to keep `<center></center>` and be prepared in case its ever removed, add this to your css

```
center{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: That's it. With this few-line fix, you're future-proof.

Comment: (Notice, however, that display:flex will have side effects. But we get the point.)

Answer (score 4):

Food for thought: what would a text-to-speech synthesizer do with `<center>`?

Comment: Probably speak "center" or "centered".

Comment: The same as it would do with css' text-align: center; I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, nah, what would it do with "display:inline-block; color:#772fe3; background-repeat:no-repeat; border:17px dotted beige; transform:rotate(3deg)"? I would totally be confused as a screen reader. I think I'd just go with the text. Duh.

Comment: ...and okay, maybe you're saying "markup should always have a speech representation"; but no, absolutely not, see "div" or "span" for example. HTML is for documents, SSML is for speech.

Answer (score 3):

CSS has a `text-align: center` property, and since this is purely a visual thing, not semantic, it should be relegated to CSS, not HTML.

Comment: +1 for explaining why it was deprecated in addition to an alternative.

Comment: but `text-align` will align the content of the container, not the container itself

Comment: Ah, yeah, if it's a block-level element, "auto" padding will do it.  If it's an inline element, use `text-align: center` on its parent element.

Comment: (oops, I meant auto margin, not padding)

Comment: @AndreasGrech — `<center>` does *both*. It's annoyingly broad.

Comment: Actually, center does something that can only be expressed with a longer CSS. This, in itself, should be a reason to let the poor thing live. It's a simple form of centering the container and the contents - and there's CSS for anything more specific. Still can't see the point of being against it.

Answer (score 0):

Center is loved in HTML because it is a fast way to prototype your work without the hassle of setting up the CSS in the early stages of your work. Of course, having center used on your finished page becomes a chore in comparison to using CSS to create global centers for various elements. Thus, center will always have a place on the web, and there are still some old school forums around that format centered elements in their posts this way.

In other words, Love the center tag because it's cute and efficient when you need it!

PS: Marquee is also a classic HTML tag that is still around and that looks freaking awesome ^__^