# Centering all HTML form elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

How do you center all form label and input fields using CSS?

How would you do this for a form with label text (block) on top of the input field?

```css
#fieldset label {
    display: block;    
}

#fieldset input {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    height: 1.2em;
    width: 15em;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean? do you want to centre the form within the page? or the elements within the form? or the text within the elements?

Comment: i'd like to center both!

Comment: A Frequently Duplicated Question. The most recent dupe I'm aware of is <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html>, which also has a useful answer or two.

Comment: Lemme try that link again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Comment: i've actually thoroughly googled for an answer to my specific case... couldn't find one. in a way, it's basically just a css replacement for center, but you don't think of that when you encounter the problem from the other side.

Comment: @carl-smotricz ... just tried the margin: 0 auto solution in the link you sent. does not solve my problem.  :-(

Answer (score 8):

As Boldewyn and Ben said, text-align will centre inline items (such as spans). To centre block elements (such as divs and forms and paragraphs), give it a width and set margin-right and margin-left to auto.

It's important to understand the [difference between block and inline elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/).

Answer (score 5):

```
form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

It depends on both your HTML and your current CSS. The above is a starting point.

Comment: All inline elements are effected by text-align. Just block elements that wont be centered.

Comment: That centers only the labels, but not the actual input fields.

Answer (score 1):

The usual "centering" used for form labels and inputs is actually 2 columns, labels right-aligned and input-fields left-aligned.

One way to do this without tables is to give the label elements the same width and right-align them, for example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .foolabel{width:10em;text-align:right;display:inline-block;margin-right:1em;}
  .formlist{list-style:none}
</style>
<ul class="formlist">
  <li><label class="foolabel">Name:</label><input type="text" /></li>
  <li><label class="foolabel">Quest:</label><input type="text" /></li>
  <li><label class="foolabel">Favorite Color:</label><input type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```