# Equivalent to <center> tag in CSS?

Tags: html, center, css

I read that the `<center>` tag is deprecated, however I cannot find any real equivalent to it in CSS. `text-align` works for text but not other elements, and auto margins only work if you know the width of the container (so not a solution if you don't know the width in advance). So is there any real equivalent to this `<center>` tag?

Comment: Answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`text-align` should work for other kinds of elements.  Does this work?

```
.center { margin: auto; text-align: center; }
```

Edit Three Years Later :-D

`margin: auto;` also makes the top and bottom margins "auto".  That might not be what you want.  Alternatively you could have something like:

```css
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This particular example will center the text horizontally while hardwiring the upper and lower margins to 3 pixels.

One can also say something like `margin: 3px auto 3px auto;` but I prefer spelling out the directions explicitly, as I can never quite remember what the order of the parameters are if I put them all on the one `margin:` setting.

Comment: To remind myself of the order of the parameters for the "shorthand", I think of the word, **"terrible"**.  Like, "Wow, this shorthand syntax is terrible." :)  (TRBL: **Top Right Bottom Left**)

Comment: goes clockwise, starting at the top.

Comment: center also does something "else" that is important, it makes himself a width:100%  container. 

That's why for some those 2 (margin: auto; text-align: center;) won't work while center tag will

Answer (score 12):

## There is a difference:

```html
<center>
  <span>Works</span>
</center>

<span style="margin: auto; text-align: center;"> And this is broken</span>

<div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;">But this works works</div>
```

Comment: You can use <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center;"><span> And this was broken</span><div> or set your span to display: block

Comment: But span is an "inline element"