# iText - the PDF is not good

Tags: java, itext

I have the following HTML:

```
<div align='center' style='height:50px'>
    <H1>A Simple Sample Web Page</H1>
    <IMG SRC='http://sheldonbrown.com/images/scb_eagle_contact.jpeg'>
    <H4>By Sheldon Brown</H4>
    <H2>Demonstrating a few HTML features</H2>
</div>
HTML is really a very simple language. '
<P>
'command, which will insert a blank line.If you would like to make a link or 
bookmark to this page, the URL is:
<BR> 
http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html
</center>
```

But the image appears behind the text instead of below!

What's wrong?

if iText cannot handle it - which library is better?

This is my code:

```
// step 1
        Document document = new Document();

        // step 2
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\hello-world.pdf"));

        document.open();
        String content = "<div align='center' style='height:50px'><H1>A Simple Sample Web Page</H1><IMG SRC='http://sheldonbrown.com/images/scb_eagle_contact.jpeg'><H4>By Sheldon Brown</H4><H2>Demonstrating a few HTML features</H2></div>HTML is really a very simple language. '<P>' command, which will insert a blank line.If you would like to make a link or bookmark to this page, the URL is:<BR> http://sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html</center>";

        // use the snippet for the PDF document
        List<Element> objects = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(content), null);
        for (Element element : objects)
            document.add(element);
        document.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried searching the iText mailing list? There is a mirror of it here: http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/

Comment: Maybe you should put your text and your image into different div-tags.

Comment: @Stephan I tried to put it in 2 different tags - but still it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an old version.

I switched to the last one - 5.1.2 and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any css applied to this HTML? Have you achieved to view this HTML in any other way with a browser (which) ? It renders like you describe here: http://jsfiddle.net/TjUSJ/.

Maybe you want to remove the height styling property on that `<div>`? It seems like it renders on the middle, but it is actually rendernig at 50px from the top. See this other fiddle, without `height` styling: http://jsfiddle.net/TjUSJ/1/

Also, remember that the [`<center>` tag is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798817/851811)

Comment: Yes - I tried to remove the height (as you mentioned in your second example)- but still it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with iText. I've used [Flying Saucer XHTML Renderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) with good results, though. It uses iText behind the scenes. Take into account that it'll require your document to be XHTML