# How to align an input tag to the center without specifying the width?

Tags: html, css

I have these HTML and CSS:

```css
#siteInfo input[type="button"] {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #66A3D2;
  border-color: #FFFFFF #327CB5 #327CB5 #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333333;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="siteInfo">
  <p>Some paragraph.</p>
  <input type="button" value="Some Button">
</div>
```

I'd like the button to be aligned to the center; however, even with `text-align: center` in the CSS, is still on the left. I also don't want to specify the width since I'd like it to change with the length of the text. How do I do that?

I know the solution to this is simple but I can't find a proper way to do it. I would sometimes wrap it around a `<p>` tag that is center aligned but that's extra mark-up which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to put the `text-align:center` on the containing div, not on the input itself.

Comment: This worked thanks. I'm just wondering why such is the case? Is it because input is an inline element and not a block element like <p>? If I put center align on <p> tag itself, it works fine. Just wondering why I can't do the same for <input>.

Comment: It is because the `center` attribute affects what is inside the element on which it is declared. That is, everything between `<p>` and `</p>`, and also everything between `<input>` and `</input>`, which is likely nothing as you have abbreviated it to `<input />` or even `<input>`.

Comment: this seems to conflict with `display:inline-flex`, where it stops working

Answer (score 25):

You can use the following CSS for your input field:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Then,update your input field as following:

```
<input class="center-block" type="button" value="Some Button">
```

Comment: or just :   display: block;
        margin:auto;

Answer (score 13):

write this:

```
#siteInfo{text-align:center}
p, input{display:inline-block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XfSz6/

Comment: This is an important step. If the display is just "block", it won't center, even if "text-align: center" is set on an outer container.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this two simple line code :

```css
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

To have `text-align:center` work you need to add that style to the `#siteInfo` div or wrap the input in a paragraph and add `text-align:center` to the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

you can put  in a table cell and then align the cell content.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Some Button">
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for formatting! The 90's were 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```html
<div align="center">
  <input type="button" value="Some Button">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -8):

You can also use the  tag, this works in divs and everything else:

```
<center><form></form></center>
```

This link will help you with the tag:

[Why is the <center> tag deprecated in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html/1798853#1798853)

Comment: This is the worst possible thing to do. And the link *literally* says it's deprecated.