# HTML: How to center align a form

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code and I want to make my form aligned in center.

```
<form action="advsearcher.php" method="get">
    Search this website:<input align="center" type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 66):

@Lucius and  @zyrolasting have it right.

However, you will probably need to give the form a specified `width` for it to work properly.

```
form { 
margin: 0 auto; 
width:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Just put some CSS into the stylesheet like this

```
form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

then you're done!

Comment: @JohannBehrens: Why exactly is it bad practice?

Comment: @anonymous: You will want to separate semantics and design from each other by using ONLY HTML in an .html-file and ONLY CSS in a .css-file. Makes your code clean and structured, readable for other developers or designers, future-proof and I could go on for a lot longer.

Comment: text-align:center works . Just use it in a css file and all is well. You may use <center> in the HTML as well , but as @JohannBehrens pointed out , style must be separate . Morever <center> is obsolete. My best bet is text-align:center in a stylesheet on the form tag.

Comment: that will make all forms on your site center aligned.

Comment: this centres the text within the form, not the form within the window .. is the question ambiguous?

Answer (score 22):

Being `form` a block element, you can center-align it by setting its side margins to auto:

```
form { margin: 0 auto; }
```

**EDIT:**
As @moomoochoo correctly pointed out, this rule will only work if the block element (your form, in this case) has been assigned a specific width.
Also, this 'trick' will not work for floating elements.

Answer (score 5):

This will have the field take 50% of the width and be centered and resized properly

```
    {    
        width: 50%;
        margin-left : 25%
    }
```

May also use "vw" (view width) units instead of "%"

Answer (score 4):

Use `center`:

`<center><form></form></center>`

This is just one method, though it's not [advised.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html/1798853#1798853)

Ancient Edit: Please do not do this. I am just saying it is a thing that exists.

Comment: <center> is deprecated since HTLM 4

Comment: @epox as explained in the link

Comment: Still works and recognised in browsers, but as Cilan mentioned, not advised.

Answer (score 2):

The last two lines are important to align in center:

```
.f01 {
    background-color: rgb(16, 216, 252);
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move `align="center"` to the `form` tag.

```html
<form align="center" action="advsearcher.php" method="get">
    Search this website:<input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: There's no align attribute in [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Answer (score 0):

```
#form{
   position:fixed;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   width:250px;
}
```

You can adjust top & left depending on form size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Set the width of the form as 20% by: 
    `width : 20%;`
now if the entire canvas is 100 %, the centre is at 50%. So to align the centre of the form at the centre, 50-(20/2) = 40.
therefore set your left margin as 40% by doing this :
    `left : 40%;`

Answer (score -1):

simple way:Add a "center" tag before the form tag

Comment: Center is deprecated.

Answer (score -2):

```
<center><form></form></center>
```

does work in most cases like The Wobbuffet mentioned above...

Comment: -1 `<center>` is deprecated.

1. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)
2. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Comment: Still works and recognised in browsers, but not advised.