# How can center a div which has "position" styles and content inside?

Tags: css

How can center a div which has "position" styles and content inside? I have the next code:

```
<div class="block" id="block1" style="position:relative;">
    <img />

    <div id="temperature" style="position:absolute; top:50px; min-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <div id="tempeControl" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; ">   
        <button id="minus" style="height: 28px; width:128px;">-</button>
        <span id="valueTempe" style="font-weight: bold; color: #fea100; width:28px;">0</span>
        <button id="plus" style="height: 28px; width:128px;">+</button> 
    </div>              
</div>
```

I've tried with `<center>` , `text-align:center` (I think that are the same), and `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

Comment: I would avoid the `<center>` tag altogether no matter what you're doing, as it is deprecated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Answer (score 1):

When you have an absolute position, use the following:
`left: 50%; margin-left: -200px` Change the `200px` to half of your element's width, including padding.