# Adding text over an image in the middle

Tags: html, image, text, alignment

I want to add some text over an image in the middle. I use this code:

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/game-hearts-icon.png); height: 64px; width: 64px; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">text</div>
```

I want the text to be in the middle of the heart. But it just appears in the top centered. The vertical alignment doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? 
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `line-height` to equal the height of your div:

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/game-hearts-icon.png); height: 64px; width: 64px; text-align: center; line-height: 64px;">text</div>
```

Better yet, don't use inline styles:

HTML

```
<div class="game-hearts-icon">text</div>
```

CSS

```
.game-hearts-icon {
    background: transparent url(../images/game-hearts-icon.png) scroll 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 64px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use absolute positioning, or line height to achieve the result you want, here's how: jsfiddle.net/YZXVe/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<center>` inside the div. It will put your text in the center, vertically and horizontally.

```
   <div>
    <center>
      <p>Your Text</p>
    </center>
   </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Saswata: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html