# Simple center a object with css and no hacks

Tags: html, css, center

I want to center an object using CSS and no hacks, is this possible and how?

I have tried this, but than my p tag is gone.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: What do you consider a hack?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's several ways to center an element. But it depends on what your element is and how we choose to display it:

- If you have `{display:inline; }`

  This is simple. You can just use "text-align: center;" to center text, images and divs.
- If you have `{display:block;}`

  This is a bit more difficult. It depends on how your object is positioned. Your object could be relative, absolute, or fixed.

  - If it is relative; then you can use `"margin:0 auto;"`, however you will require a width value.
  - If it is absolutely positioned, then you need to specify your `"top:"` and `"left:"` values. You'll also need a width. If you know the width of the element, the best way is to use `{left:50%; margin-left:-X}`, where X = 1/2 the width of the element.

Comment: Oke nice, so if I want to center text and an image inside a paragraph, than I can use the css `display: inline;` ?

Comment: `text-align: center;` works for me absolute good! Thank you! @CharlieM

Answer (score 6):

HTML:

```
<div>Centered</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/v3WL5/

Note that `margin: 0 auto;` will only have an effect if the `div` has a width.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin: auto` like this:

```
margin: 0px auto
```

Comment: and use position:relative; !

Answer (score 1):

Use this for general purposes. Even span or div which is inside whatever :

```
width:inherit; display:block;margin:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage :

1. In-Line usage : Content goes
   here....
2. CSS Code :

   `#text-align 
     {
       text-align:center
     }`

HTML Code :

`<div id="text-align">Content goes here....</div>`

http://www.techulator.com/resources/4299-center-Deprecated-tags-HTML.aspx

Answer (score 0):

late into the game, but have you tried with **`display:flex`** on the parent ?

I have a useful class that is **simple** and **works with all type of elements**:

```css
/* apply this on the parent */
.center {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center; /*vertical alignement*/
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignement*/
}
```

This is relatively new but [supported at ~98% of major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

However I suggest that you learn a bit about flexBox, it may seem complicated at first but it is very powerful for all type layouts !

Answer (score -4):

if you don't need to be position:fixed; you can just use

```
<center>
Hello
</center>
```

This is deprecated in HTML5

Comment: the center tag was deprecated. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) for why

Comment: The <center> tag is supported in all major browsers but it's not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.