# How to center multiple line text in html using css, just like <center>?

Tags: html, css

I have this html content:

```
<div class="test">
  <a href=/cgi-bin/source/sourceSearch><img border=0 src=http://source-search.princeton.edu/images/SOURCE/sourcehdrBlue.gif></a>
  <h2 style='margin-bottom:0px'>BATCH</h2>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
    <tr>
      <td><h3>SOURCE is now hosted by Princeton University. The supporting database was last updated on June 10, 2015. </h3> <p>This page is the batch extract interface for SOURCE.  You can input a list of GenBank Accessions, dbEST cloneIDs, UniGene ClusterIDs, UniGene gene names, UniGene gene symbols microarray Probes from various platforms (Affymetrix, Agilent, Heebo/meebo, Illumina) or coordinates (e.g.: chr1 14565 15000 - chromosome, from, to - one set per line) and retrieve data from the checklist below.  You will be given a link to the output file when processing is complete.</p> <p>You may enter the identifiers as a file or as a list in the text area below.  If you are entering an input file, it must be a text file consisting of a single column containing one of the accepted types of identifiers.</p> <p>Please see the <a href="http://source-search.princeton.edu/help/SOURCE/resultsBatchHelp.html">help</a> section for further information. Or go to <a href="http://source-search.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/source/sourceSearch">Single Entry SOURCE Search.</a> </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Just adding `<center>... </center>` surround all these code, that is what I want.
[image]
 Since `<center>` tag was deprecated in HTML, I want to use css instead of `<center>`. My css code likes this:

```
div.test {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
```

}

I got this:
[image]

I tried everything I can find, but all of them not work for me. I use windows 7 and chrome, I have seen [Why is the <center> tag deprecated in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) and [Simple center a object with css and no hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883805/simple-center-a-object-with-css-and-no-hacks?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: You are worried about using the deprecated element `<center>`, but apparently you have no qualms about `border`, `cellpadding` and `width` attributes, that are just as deprecated!

Comment: And I wish I could say you were using a table for layout purposes. (That would've been a reason to use a table, although not a valid one.) But you aren't, you're using a table for _no purpose at all!_ Why? Oh, and the unquoted src URL makes me itch.

Comment: @MrLister, take it easy, it's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a reason why you using `<table>`?

change your css:

```
    div.test {
text-align: center;
}

div table{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

fiddle

[click here for your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ak2o76pj/1/)

this will answer you why `<center>` is deprecated
[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html)

Comment: Wow! It works for me, but can you give me an explanation? What does auto margin in table do?

Comment: when you set the margin to auto the element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the left and right margins. 0 before mean - zero margin top and bottom.

Comment: look at this example without table tag. https://jsfiddle.net/ak2o76pj/3/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test
{
  text-align:center;
}
   div table
   {
  margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href=/cgi-bin/source/sourceSearch><img border=0 src=http://source-search.princeton.edu/images/SOURCE/sourcehdrBlue.gif></a>
  <h2 style='margin-bottom:0px'>BATCH</h2>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="text-align:center">
    <tr>
      <td><h3>SOURCE is now hosted by Princeton University. The supporting database was last updated on June 10, 2015. </h3> <p>This page is the batch extract interface for SOURCE.  You can input a list of GenBank Accessions, dbEST cloneIDs, UniGene ClusterIDs, UniGene gene names, UniGene gene symbols microarray Probes from various platforms (Affymetrix, Agilent, Heebo/meebo, Illumina) or coordinates (e.g.: chr1 14565 15000 - chromosome, from, to - one set per line) and retrieve data from the checklist below.  You will be given a link to the output file when processing is complete.</p> <p>You may enter the identifiers as a file or as a list in the text area below.  If you are entering an input file, it must be a text file consisting of a single column containing one of the accepted types of identifiers.</p> <p>Please see the <a href="http://source-search.princeton.edu/help/SOURCE/resultsBatchHelp.html">help</a> section for further information. Or go to <a href="http://source-search.princeton.edu/cgi-bin/source/sourceSearch">Single Entry SOURCE Search.</a> </p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

table { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; }

div.test { text-align: center; }