# SudoSlider (javascript). Different view in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, carousel

I inserted SudoSlider in my website. It works fine in all major browsers, but safari chashes my slider. Can you tell, please where the problem is?

```
http://81.198.86.35:8084/nv/course/10/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, so i can only test in the latest version of Safari for Windows (5.1.7).

You have a center tag around SudoSlider, and that seems to cause the problems.

<center> has been deprecated for quite a while (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp), and isn't even supported in HTML 5.

So you can't expect the center tag to work, remove it and use CSS instead. Here's a guide to how: [Why is the <center> tag deprecated in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html)