# Change content in row onclick of navgation button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the content of the row with the click on the tabs in the navigation bar. The row would be static but the content should change. The content below the top heading, "ASSOCIATE SOFTWARE ENGINEER PROGRAM" should change when I click on the Navigation bar links.

I need help on how to link the navigation bar to the content. The content in the row should move when I click on the navigation bar links.  The default view is 'About'. When I click on 'Get Involved', the content in the row which has the image and the text should change to something else related.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.ms-quicklaunchheader {
    display:none;
}

.ms-recyclebin{
    display:none;
}

.ms-sitetitle {
    display:none;
}
p.wide-tracking { letter-spacing: 0.3em }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<CENTER>
<TABLE width="640" align="center" style="LINE-HEIGHT: normal; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 10px; FONT-SIZE: medium; font-family: Cambria, 'Hoefler Text', 'Liberation Serif', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;" summary="">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=bottom colSpan=6 align=center><IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; WIDTH: 650px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid" border=0 src="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/images1/ASE_top_banner.jpg" useMap=#bannermap></TD><MAP name=bannermap><AREA href="#" shape=rect alt="Event Tools" coords=521,89,634,121><AREA href="#" shape=rect alt="Events" coords=410,88,519,123><AREA href="#" shape=rect alt="Get Involved" coords=298,89,407,122><AREA href="#" shape=rect alt="About Us" coords=183,89,297,124></MAP></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=6 align=middle>
<P align=center><FONT style="letter-spacing: 0.07em" size=6 face="CA Sans">ASSOCIATE SOFTWARE ENGINEER PROGRAM</FONT></P></TD></TR></TBODY>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height=5 colSpan=6>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=2 colSpan=3 align="center"><IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; WIDTH: 310px; HEIGHT: 193px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid" border=0 src="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/images1/iPad.jpg"></TD>
<TD height=2 colSpan="3" align="left"><strong><FONT color=#95A0A8 size=3 face=Calibri>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</FONT></strong></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=20 colSpan=6>
<HR style="HEIGHT: 1px" class=style2></TD></TR></TBODY>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=middle rowSpan=2 colSpan=2 align=left>
<IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; WIDTH: 216px; HEIGHT: 162px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid" border=0 src="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/images1/Map.jpg"></TD>
<TD vAlign="middle" rowSpan=2 colSpan=2 align=center>
<P align=center><IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; WIDTH: 216px; HEIGHT: 162px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid" border=0 src="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/images1/Demo1.jpg"></P></TD>
<TD rowspan="2" vAlign="middle" colSpan=2 align=right><IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; WIDTH: 216px; HEIGHT: 162px; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid" border=0 src="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/images1/tab3.jpg" width="216" height="162" usemap="#rowmap"/>
  <map name="rowmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,97,156,113" href="www.thehub.ca.com">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,45,155,61" href="www.thehub.ca.com">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,11,155,27" href="www.thehub.ca.com">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,29,155,45" href="www.thehub.ca.com">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,63,155,79" href="www.thehub.ca.com">
  <area shape="rect" coords="22,80,157,96" alt="Venus" href="www.thehub.ca.com">
</map></TD>
</tr>
<tr>
<TD height=20 rowspan="2" vAlign=center colSpan=6 align=middle>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<TD height=20 vAlign=center colSpan=6 align=middle>
<HR style="HEIGHT: 1px" class=style2>
</td>
</tr>
<TR>
<TD width="98%" colSpan=6 align="left">
<P><FONT size="5" color=#e98300 face="Calibri">"The ASE program hust had a great vibe. The instructors were excellent. Everyone from CA was deeply dedicated to the program and our projects. And these weren't school projects-my team did real work for an actual CA product. At the end we presented our projects to several VPs. It was an awesome program. I only wish it was longer."</FONT></FONT></P>
<P align=right><STRONG>Justin Hegedus</STRONG><BR>Associate Engineer<BR>CA Technologies</P></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD height=20 vAlign=center colSpan=6 align=middle>
<HR style="HEIGHT: 1px" class=style2>
</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD colSpan=6>
<P align=left><FONT size=3 face=Calibri><STRONG>Legacy ASE Site Content (Temporary).</STRONG></FONT></P>
<P align=left><FONT face=Calibri><A title="" href="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/Distributed/Forms/AllItems.aspx" target=_blank>Distributed</A> <BR><A title="" href="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/Mainframe/Forms/AllItems.aspx" target=_blank>Mainframe <BR></A><A title="" href="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/General/Forms/AllItems.aspx" target=_blank>General <BR></A><A title="" href="https://km.ca.com/rnd/vitality/ase/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" target=_blank>Shared Documents</A></FONT></P></TD></TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE></CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried anything? plz post the code to see where you got stuck.

Comment: fiddle it.. and explain your problem briefly

Comment: I need help on how to link the navigation bar to the content. The content in the row should move when I click on the navigation bar links.

Comment: Also, please never use the `<center>` tag. This is obselete (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html)