# Center a CSS box?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
    <center>
        <div class="xmdiv">
            <img class="xmenu" src="media/file1.png">
            <img class="xmenu" src="media/file2.png">
        </div>
    </center>
    <p>-snip-</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cont {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 3%;
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 65%;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 1px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        color: #070707;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:300;
        text-align:justified;
        line-height:1.5;
}
p {
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

What it looks like:
[image]

I want it to be centered, how do I do that? Tried looking it up online, and it didn't really work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 1):

To center a div (and many other types of elements), use this CSS code:

```
.cont { 
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: XXXpx;
}
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TV4n5/)

Make sure to specify the width, or else the div won't be centered.

## Edit

To center an element without specifying with, you could do something like this (not sure if this will work in all browsers, however):

```
body { text-align:center; }
.cont { display:inline-block; }
```

### Side-note

Don't use the center tag, it is deprecated. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html).

Comment: Is there a way to make it centered permanently, meaning I wont have to change it later? Instead of putting in numbers, can I put something that will auto-center it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ? Link: http://jsfiddle.net/jtFUs/

**CSS:**

```
.cont
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to center a div vertically and horizontally on your page, use:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000000;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/48/

In case you need to center it just horizontally, use:

```
center
{
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Just define a width for the element, in this case i added 200px for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/50/

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be `center` in your CSS.