# button not centering inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm using `margin: 0 auto` but the button seems not to respond that and does not center inside div.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/4L3ug/)

HTML:

```
<div class="ou">
    <div class="con">
        <button>some</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ou{
    width: 33%;
    height: 26px;
    background: blue;
}

.con{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.con button{
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
display: block;
```

to the .con button rule 
http://jsfiddle.net/5PqmV/

Answer (score 3):

add     text-align: center; to .ou. Here:

```
.ou{
    width: 33%;
    height: 26px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.con{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.con button{
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: BTW, `margin: 0 auto` works for block elements, and the button is an inline element. That's why you either have to center text with `text-align` or add `display: block` to the button.

Answer (score 1):

Either give "`display:block`" to

```
.con button{
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L3ug/1/**

OR

Give "`text-align:center;`" to :

```
.con{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L3ug/2/**

Hope this should help!!

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer is not to use CSS. Use the  tag in HTML instead.

```
<div class="ou">
    <div class="con">
        <center><button>some</button></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This violates separation of concerns principle. Please see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html