# how to override p:selectOneRadio default icons

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, overriding, jsf-2.2

I have the following `p:selectOneRadio` :

```
  <p:outputPanel id="customPanel">  

         <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{dyna.selecetedlist}" layout="grid" columns="1">  
           <c:forEach var="list" items="#{dyna.userlist}" varStatus="loop">
                   <f:selectItem  itemEscaped="true" itemLabel="#{list.id.tbCode}" itemValue="#{list.id.tbCode}" />  
           </c:forEach>
           <p:ajax update=":form1:tabexam,:form1:msg,:form1:colser" listener="#{dyna.updatecolumns}"/>
          </p:selectOneRadio>  

   </p:outputPanel>
```

which generate this :

[image]

What i want is to override the default icons and layout of `p:selectOneRadio`.
and render it like below:

[image]

Comment: Just one point `<center>` has been deprecated in HTML and should no longer be used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize the icon, override the `.ui-radiobutton-icon` on your page (there is a cleaner option of including a properly packaged css file):

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .ui-radiobutton-icon{
       background: url(imgs/icon.png) no-repeat; !important;
   }
 </style>
```

---

EDIT: Override the

- `.ui-state-hover` class to override the default hover style for the component
- `.ui-state-active` clasas to override the default selected style for the component

**Note** overriding both classes as listed above will affect *all* the components on that page. Be sure to use a custom namespace when overriding. Take for example

```
 .my-custom-ns .ui-state-hover{
  //css
  }
```

And then in your component definition:

```
  <p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" value="#{dyna.selecetedlist}" styleClass="my-custom-ns" layout="grid" columns="1">  
       <c:forEach var="list" items="#{dyna.userlist}" varStatus="loop">
               <f:selectItem  itemEscaped="true" itemLabel="#{list.id.tbCode}" itemValue="#{list.id.tbCode}" />  
       </c:forEach>
       <p:ajax update=":form1:tabexam,:form1:msg,:form1:colser" listener="#{dyna.updatecolumns}"/>
      </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: how about when selected, and hover ?