# Center text inside two divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, centering

How to I can I center this texts horizontally which is inside two divs. When I'm previewing it in Dreamweaver, it is finely centered.

My HTML codes:

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="microcontainers">  
         <p class="design"><span style="color: #F90;">D</span>ESIGN</p>  
    </div>  
    <div class="microcontainers">  
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS Style:

```
#maincontainer{   
    width:1120px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#E4E4E4;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 124px;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
    text-align: center; 
}

.microcontainers{
    width: 350px;
    height: 600px;
    border:  #999 1px solid;
    margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.design{
    font-family: TrajanPro-Regular; 
    font-size:85px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thank you and more power!

Comment: You are using `#maincontainer` (id-selector) in your CSS and `class="maincontainer"` in your HTML. If you want the CSS rule to apply you should change it to `.maincontainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v Please try this, it may solve your problem.

There is some CSS changes.

```
.microcontainers{
    width: 350px;
    height: 600px;
    border:  #999 1px solid;
    margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.design{
    font-family: TrajanPro-Regular; 
    font-size:85px;
    color: #999;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5uhJF/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center` for the paragraph.

```
.design{
    font-family: TrajanPro-Regular; 
    font-size:85px;
    color: #999;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I forgot to put centering tags. I've used text-align: center, display:block, margin: 0 auto ect... but to no avail..

Answer (score 1):

Your content "DESIGN" seem to be overflowing its container thus placing it off-center. Look at this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bq852/4/)** where I have added `overflow: hidden` to `.design`.

With your updated CSS, including `text-align: center` for `.design` you could either **[reduce the `font-size`](http://jsfiddle.net/bq852/1/)**, reduce the **[padding of `.microcontainers`](http://jsfiddle.net/bq852/2/)** or **[add negative margin on the `<p>` element](http://jsfiddle.net/bq852/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

add

```
text-align:center;
```

in your design class

Answer (score 0):

Just adding text alignment will fix it see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JET2/) 
doing exactly what the above user suggested.

> ```
> .design{
> font-family: TrajanPro-Regular; 
> font-size:85px;
> color: #999;
>     text-align: center;
> }
> ```

but I don't see why you are doing this can you explain it..If you are doing a big project i suggest you use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)

Comment: Thanks Yonas T. in fiddle it works. But on browsers, like Chrome and Google it wont. The text is thrown to the right side of the div despite of all the centering tags. Thanks!

Comment: @JOEMAYA Chrome and Google are same by the way.

Comment: Have you tried to make the font size for the design class smaller? I think you should Start by small font size then try to scale it up. It will help you see where the problem came from.

Comment: Yup. I tried. I started 12pts. It's still a aligned right. Now, I figured it out. Thanks man!

Comment: No problem dude! Nice that you finally got it fixed.

Answer (score -2):

You can use center tags also

```
<div class="maincontainer">
    <center><div class="microcontainers">  
         <p class="design"><span style="color: #F90;">D</span>ESIGN</p>  
    </div></center>
    <center><div class="microcontainers">  
    </div></center>
</div>
```

Comment: While true, you shouldn't suggest that people make use of a depreciated tag. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) for some details.

Comment: Thanks Sam. But <center> tag seems to don't work either.

Comment: Remember the tag `<center>` is not supported by HTML5. And should not be used.