# Is it possible to center tables in a markdown file?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, apiblueprint, apiary.io

I have a table:

```
    | This | Is | A | Table |
    | :--- | -- | - | ----: |
    | foo  | ba | r | elbaT |
```

I'd like the table to display in the center of my Markdown file instead of left-aligned. I am not trying to align text, but the entire table itself. Do I need to resort to HTML/CSS to achieve what I want?

This is for an Apiary.io project.

Comment: For Material for MkDocs: https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/3430#issuecomment-1005973474

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[My solution detailed by Gaffney in an Apiary.io issue comment](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/58#issuecomment-47722652).

Basically I add custom stylesheets and scripts within apiary.apib HTML blocks to style the page with HTML instead of headwalling that a Markdown [di](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint)ale[ct](http://blog.apiary.io/2013/02/20/New-API-Blueprint-Format-Basics/) isn't CSS.

Also ["How to Center Anything in CSS"](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/).

Answer (score 85):

If you use the *standard* documentation, use the `<center>` tag like so.

#### Blueprint

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: http://www.google.com

# Tables
Notes API is a *short texts saving* service similar to its physical paper presence on your table.

<center>

| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |

</center>

# Group Notes

(...)
```

#### Preview

[image]

---

If you use the *‘[New Documentation](http://blog.apiary.io/2014/03/20/Re-API-Design-for-Humans/)’*, it's not possible to center a table *(since the table takes a full width of the column)*.

#### Preview

[image]

Comment: While this at least directly answers my question, the second hit on Google (for me) leads to [a StackOverflow question asking why `center` is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1798817/1708136). Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Sorry to comment after 10 years, but I just wanted to add that the empty lines between the start and end `<center>` tags and the seem to be essential (at least in my case); omitting them led to problems).

Answer (score 41):

1. **|-|** is used to indicate the table header and **:** is used to indicate text alignment. Text is **left aligned by default**.

   | Col 1 | Col 2 |
   | --- | --- |
   | Value 1 | Value 2 |
   | Value 3 | Value 4 |
2. **|:-|** is used to **left align** the text inside header and column.

   | Col 1 | Col 2 |
   | --- | --- |
   | Value 1 | Value 2 |
   | Value 3 | Value 4 |
3. **|-:|** is used to **right align** the text inside header and column.

   | Col 1 | Col 2 |
   | --- | --- |
   | Value 1 | Value 2 |
   | Value 3 | Value 4 |
4. **|:-:|** is used to **center align** the text inside header and column.

   | Col 1 | Col 2 |
   | --- | --- |
   | Value 1 | Value 2 |
   | Value 3 | Value 4 |

Comment: As is sometimes the case, the actual answer is at the bottom

Comment: The question, however, is for centering the table itself, and not its contents. I can see how it's easy to misunderstand though.

Comment: In original answer, alignments are wrongly associated with the symbols. Correct association is :- for left and -: for right.

Answer (score 16):

A simple method that everyone seems to have overlooked is to enclose the table within a `div` and use the `align="center"` property on it.

```
<div align="center">

| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |

</div>
```

Works just like `<center>` used to. No need to worry about `<center>` getting deprecated anymore. ;)

Comment: `align` attribute is also deprecated.

Answer (score 15):

Yes. You can have GFM tables in API Blueprint – check http://docs.tables.apiary.io for rendered version of the blueprint source bellow.

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Tables API 
Note: Tables can be handcrafted or generated at <http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables>.

## Table 1
**Discussion option 1**

| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |

# Message [/pages]
## Create a Message [POST]

### Table 2
**Discussion option 2**

| Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
|----------|:-------------:|------:|
| col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
| col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |

+ Request (application/json)

    ## Table 3
    **Discussion option 3**

    | Tables   |      Are      |  Cool |
    |----------|:-------------:|------:|
    | col 1 is |  left-aligned | $1600 |
    | col 2 is |    centered   |   $12 |
    | col 3 is | right-aligned |    $1 |

    + Headers

            Authorization:Bearer tokenString

    + Body

            { ... }

+ Response 201
```

Comment: Isn't the question about "centering the whole table on the page"? Whereas this response is about "centering the text within a single column"? I can't find anywhere that any Markdown variant allows centering or indenting text  (except pre/code blocks, but they also literalize the Markdown that defines the table).

Comment: Good point! I have misunderstood the answer – AFAIK there is no way to do it within Apiary. I will keep you updated on whether/how it is possible in the embedded documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From Yihui's book(https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) re: `kable()`:

> Tables are center-aligned by default when they are included in a table environment (i.e., when the table has a caption). If you do not want to center a table, use the argument centering = FALSE.