# Markdown table inside a div element

Tags: html, markdown

I am trying to center a table in markdown so i was thinking of putting it inside a div and then `text-align` the content to `center`.

```
<div class="myWrapper" markdown="1">


| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | 
| ------ | ------ | ------ | 
| r0 | r0 | r0 | 
| r1 | r1 | r1 | 
| r2 | r2 | r2 | 
| r3 | r3 | r3 | 
| r4 | r4 | r4 | 


</div>
```

But doing this will transform it into pure HTML
My question is: How can i use that markdown table inside a div ? And get properly rendered

Comment: what is your exact question? Are you looking for another method?

Comment: uh, maybe you should center the entire `myWrapper` div rather than just the content?

Comment: using pure markdown, you can only center content of column using |:---:| in splitter row

Comment: I am not trying to use pure markdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to center tables in a markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127507/is-it-possible-to-center-tables-in-a-markdown-file)

Comment: Also relevant: [How to horizontally center a `<div>` in another `<div>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114543/866026). And for an explanation of why you should be using CSS, see the accepted answer to [Is it possible to have a table in the center in Github gist markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44172954/866026) (the rest of that answer focuses on GitHub not allowing CSS, but the answer begins by explaining why this is not something Markdown supports natively).

Answer (score 4):

This answer is aside of the question. I was solving the problem of defining different table styles inside one Markdown document. I'm using [Python-Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/).

```
The default table stile: 

Item No | Name | Description | Price
--------|------|-------------|------
1       | Chair | Kitchen chair | 101.50
2       | Table | Kitchen table | 450.00

The "plated" table style:

<div class="tablePlated"></div>

|Item No | Name | Description | Price|
|--------|------|-------------|------|
|1       | Chair | Kitchen chair | 101.50|
|2       | Table | Kitchen table | 450.00|

And the "gridded" table style:

<div class="tableGridded"></div>

Item No | Name | Description | Price
--------|------|-------------|------
1       | Chair | Kitchen chair | 101.50
2       | Table | Kitchen table | 450.00
```

Here are the CSS rules:

```css
table {
    font-size: 16px;
}

td, th {
    padding: 7px 14px;
}

div.tablePlated+table {
    border-spacing: 1px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

div.tablePlated+table td, div.tablePlated+table th {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

div.tableGridded+table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;    
}

div.tableGridded+table td, div.tableGridded+table th {
    border: solid 1px dodgerblue;
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style *emphasis* inside an HTML block.

but

> Unlike block-level HTML tags, Markdown syntax is processed within span-level tags.

Comment: Changing from div to span will not wrap my table but create the span element inside a <p> with no text in it and after the </p> is the table placed

Comment: @aNNgeL0, For an explanation of why that happens, see the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273097/866026).