# CSS/HTML Sidebar being pushed down by the title text

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I recently set up a sidebar for my user panel, however it appears that it's being pushed down. I've looked at other problem threads and their solutions all give me no luck. Hoping someone can help me out figuring this out

CSS:

```
<style>


       div.menu 
{ 
width:200px; 
height:660px; 
background-color:#C0C0C0; 
left:0px; 
top:0px; 
} 

.menu ul li 
{ 
margin-bottom:20px; 
} 
body    {width: 800px; margin: 20px auto; /* center */ padding: 20px;
         border: 1px solid black;}

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<center><h3>User Panel</h3></center>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

I will post any and all things you ask for to help figure this out - hope it's detailed and as full as it needs to be to help you figure it out

Entire code:

```
<style>


       div.menu 
{ 
width:200px; 
height:660px; 
background-color:#C0C0C0; 
left:0px; 
top:0px; 
} 

.menu ul li 
{ 
margin-bottom:20px; 
} 
body    {width: 800px; margin: 20px auto; /* center */ padding: 20px;
         border: 1px solid black;}

</style>
<body>
<center><h3>User Panel</h3></center>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this, and just change the order in the html so 'center' comes after the sidebar:

```
   div.menu {
    width:200px;  
    background-color:#C0C0C0;  
    float:left;  
   }  
   center {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
   }
```

Also you could make it a class in a span or div, instead of using the deprecated center tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because the title is technically on top of the sidebar. Remove `<center>` and you will see what I mean. Let's create a solution without using `<center>` as it [is deprecated and should no longer be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html).

Here is a solution using `display: table`:

[Have a jsBin Example!](http://jsbin.com/dabud/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
        <h3>User Panel</h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

body {
  width:800px;
  margin:20px auto;
/* center */
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:table
}

body > div {
  display:table-cell
}

div.menu {
  width:200px;
  height:660px;
  background-color:silver;
  padding:10px
}

.menu ul li {
  margin-bottom:20px;
  list-style:none
}

h3 {
  text-align:center
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, it's now putting User Panel on the bottom. This is my entire code, including php. http://pastebin.com/9pgdJMJp

Comment: You have the `<body>` twice, that could cause this issue :)

Comment: Also, what is in `header.php`?

Answer (score 0):

The title is an `h3` element which is a block level element. It automatically takes some margin by default. Remove margin from `h3` to solve the issue.

```
center h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Note:** The `ul` tag also take some margins by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want to achieve exactly without knowing your envisioned layout and content.

But you are using left and top properties with your menu style and those won't do anything without specifying position as absolute, fixed or relative.

Try to do this:

```
div.menu 
{
  position:absolute; 
  width:200px; 
  height:660px; 
  background-color:#C0C0C0; 
  left:0px; 
  top:0px; 
}
```

The sidebar will no longer be pushed down. But it will also be taken out of the layout flow. So in your example the h3 (and all other content on the page) will now extend underneath the sidebar. That might not be what you want.

If you want to build a multi-column layout you should consider to use a CSS framework, such as for example Twitter Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: I did have an absolute position, but then it took the bar out of the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have the top and left attributes set, but no position. You need to add

```
position: absolute;
```

to your menu css to get it to stay positioned at the top. It will overlap the h3 you have there, but you can play around with z-index and margin to fix that.

I hope this helps, please let me know if you need any further explanation.
 :)