# How to make an image stay in the middle after the 'transform: scale' is applied?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, transform

This fiddle demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pn04dsvq/

I need to use the `transform: scale` for the image at the top for viewports below 500px. However for some reason after the scaling is applied the image stays on the right. I would like the image to stay in the middle horizontally.

I've tested the `transform: scale` function on the text at the bottom and it manages to stay in the middle. Would you know how I can achieve this for the image at the top?

On some forums I've found a `transform-origin` property and when I add `transform-origin: left;` to the image container it keeps the image on the left, however when I add `transform-origin: center;` it does not make any difference.

Please note that I need to use only the `transform: scale` function on the image. Making the image responsive based on viewport size will not work for my application. Many thanks.

The HTML code:

```
<div id="grey-bar">
    <div id="image-container">
        <img src="http://www.refugeeweek.org.uk/Resources/RefugeeWeek2012/Images/CounterpointsArts3.bmp">
    </div>
</div>

<h3 id="main-heading">How can I make the image above to stay in the middle after the 'transform: scale' is applied for viewports below 500px? For some reason it stays on the right.</h3>

<div id="grey-bar">
    <div id="bottom-heading-container">
        <h1 id="bottom-heading">This sentance stays in the middle after the 'transform: scale' is applied.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#grey-bar {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    background-color:grey;
}
div#image-container {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    div#image-container {
        max-width:100%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align: center;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
}
h3#main-heading {
    max-width:728px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:grey;
}
div#bottom-heading-container {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    div#bottom-heading-container {
        max-width:100%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align: center;
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }
}
h1#bottom-heading {
    max-width:728px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: it does stay in centre vertically and horizontally

Comment: set logo width to 100%; so that it adjusts http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/pn04dsvq/7/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Unfortunately in my application setting the logo width to 100% will not be possible. I can only apply the scaling function.

Comment: It stays center but you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gxufphje/

Comment: @Christina Many thanks for the fiddle. However when the width is very narrow the logo still sways towards right. Whereas the sentence at the bottom stays perfectly in the center.

Comment: You need to make the image responsive. http://jsfiddle.net/gxufphje/1/

Comment: Thanks Cristina for trying to help me. I'm aware that when the image is responsive then it will stay in the center. Unfortunately in my application I can only use the transform scale function.

Answer (score 0):

On my Firefox the problem you described occurred.
I suggest adding 'center' tag to solve it:

```
<center>   </center>
```

then it showed at center on my Firefox as expected.

Since you want your img centered in your container, it should look like this:

```
<div id="image-container">
  <center>
    <img/>
  </center>
</div>
```

So as to make it compatible to both newer html5 and older html resolver, you'd better keep both "center" tag and "text-align" attr.
The code above showed to be like this:

[image: like this on my Firefox]

Comment: I've added the <center> </center> tags around the image container and it did not work. Could you please add a link to your fiddle?

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. See explanation [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1798853/1581050).

Comment: I've extended the answer above for your confusion. Please have a look if you noticed this comment.

Comment: The CSS equivalent for the `<center>` tag which is deprecated is `text-align:center;`