# Center multiples links

Tags: html, css

I've this code

```css
.inline-subtitles {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.inline-subtitles a {
    width:33%;
    padding:15px;
    background: #ececec;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-subtitles">
    <a href="#">Doc technique</a>
    <a href="#">Carnet utilisateur</a>
    <a href="#">Nomenclatures</a>
    <a href="#">Notice de pose</a>
    <a href="#">Notice réglages</a>
</div>
```

I want these links to be centered into the container `.inline-subtitles`.

I try `margin: 0 auto;` but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css rule `text-align:center;` to `.inline-subtitles a`

Answer (score 0):

Add following style to your CSS:

```
.inline-subtitles {
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can also drop this one:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsz4fo9h/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.inline-subtitles a {
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```css
.inline-subtitles {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
   
}

.inline-subtitles a {
    width:33%;
    padding:15px;
    background: #ececec;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-subtitles">
    <a href="#">Doc technique</a>
    <a href="#">Carnet utilisateur</a>
    <a href="#">Nomenclatures</a>
    <a href="#">Notice de pose</a>
    <a href="#">Notice réglages</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yous change this:

```
<div class="inline-subtitles">
<a href="#">Doc technique</a>
 <a href="#">Carnet utilisateur</a>
 <a href="#">Nomenclatures</a>
 <a href="#">Notice de pose</a>
 <a href="#">Notice réglages</a>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="inline-subtitles">
 <center> 
 <a href="#">Doc technique</a>
 <a href="#">Carnet utilisateur</a>
 <a href="#">Nomenclatures</a>
 <a href="#">Notice de pose</a>
 <a href="#">Notice réglages</a>
 </center>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7bphj3uk/)

Basically surround your `a` tags with the `center` tag

Comment: Isn't <center> tag deprecated? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html   I mean it works, but HTML is all about content and CSS should be about display aspects.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inline-subtitles {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.inline-subtitles a {
    width:33%;
    padding:15px;
    background: #ececec;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align: center; // <== just add this line...
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-subtitles">
    <a href="#">Doc technique</a>
    <a href="#">Carnet utilisateur</a>
    <a href="#">Nomenclatures</a>
    <a href="#">Notice de pose</a>
    <a href="#">Notice réglages</a>
</div>
```