# Is these style of coding correct?

Tags: html, css

I just started to learn CSS and created a sample page on my local portal. I would like to know whether these style of coding is correct or not.

I came to know that these style of coding doesn't work in major extents.

Could you correct my code according to make it much more feasible and I would try to learn some of your coding styles and will adapt it to my convinience.

Sorry if these sort of questions can't be asked in this site.

```html
<div class="initial">

<div style="position:relative; width:100%; margin-Top: 4.75%; font-size: 1.3em; font-family: Helvetica; text-align: center; background-color: #bbb;">
<center><p style='line-height:200%'>

<a href=h.php style="text-decoration: none; color:white"> Home</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<a href=click.php style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Please Click Here</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<a href=contact.php style="text-decoration: none; color:white">Contact</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<a href=about.php style="text-decoration: none; color:white">About Me</a></p></center>
    
</style>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Don't mix HTML and CSS in one file; Apply indentation to your code, so it is easier to read; Don't use &nbsp; for layout (use styles instead).

Comment: If you want code review, use code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For this sort of lines I can mix both CSS and HTML isn't it? <a href=h.php style="text-decoration: none; color:white">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first points to be noted..

1. Don't use inline CSS
2. Instead of using `&nbsp;` use either `margin` or `padding`
3. Margin and padding let's you give space between two tags

See the snippet how i implement the `padding`

```css
.initial-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-Top: 4.75%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
p {
  line-height: 200%;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="initial">

  <div class="initial-content">
    <center>
      <p>

        <a href=h.php> Home</a>
        <a href=click.php>Please Click Here</a>
        <a href=contact.php>Contact</a>
        <a href=about.php>About Me</a>
      </p>
    </center>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail code according to types.

Answer (score 2):

Things to Note:

1. HTML skeleton is missing.
2. CSS can be used seperately rather inline.
3. Instead of nbsp you need to use margins and padding. You need to know float.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Will work it out on the margins now but i would like to know why to use padding property in this code?

Comment: @Novice Think like this: "What information I want to deliver to user?" - your HTML should answer this question. "How I want it to look like?" - use CSS to achieve that.

Comment: @Novice In this example you are using `&nbsp;` for visual purposes, that should be your trigger to substitute it with correct CSS

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it 'doesn't work  in major extents', you answered half a question: it means it's not correct. What exactly is not correct:

1. Inline CSS should work fine, and you can use it for testing. But you should otherwise use a css file. Use identifiers like ids and classes.
2. *href* attribute value must be inside quotes or double quotes.
3. `</style>` closing doesn't close anything. You could use css code inside these tags, but it's more appropriate to use .css files instead.
4. `&nbsp;` thing: Use positioning css. For example, if you want the items aligned vertically, you can use `item{clear:left;float:left;}`
5. `<center>` tag is deprecated. [Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) Use instead:`<div class="centered(or whatever you feel like calling it)">` and style it:`.centered{width: 60%;margin:auto;}`

But the rest is just right.