# if isset submit failed

Tags: php

```
$jepse = $_POST['slj'];
if(isset($jepse)){
    $sql43 = "UPDATE notifications SET seen='1' WHERE touser='$myid' ";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql43)){
    }}  
?>
<center>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="slj" value="Seen" style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0); ">
</form>
</center>
```

I have very stupid problem here... My submit button wont set ..... Don't know what is problem... I have many same things on different pages and with different names... But for this it wont work .... Anyone help?

:::::::::::::::::::UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::

I did it with moving update code to another file and at action set that file...

Comment: check in your form which method are you use?

Comment: it is in code.... post

Comment: Do you get any errors from PHP? or white screen?

Comment: no.... should i use button tag ?

Comment: Side note: the [`<center>` tag is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1798853/3294262) and not supported in HTML 5. Consider using CSS instead.

Comment: no, input `type=submit` works as well. change your `if` to `if(isset($_POST['slj']))` see any change ?

Comment: @AlaaA.F. ill try ...  ill remove center also and try it

Comment: write print_r($_POST) above if() condition and check what is perameter come.

Comment: @MayankVadiya got Array

Comment: please can you see that Array. @StupidProgrammer

Comment: or i am really stupid or i cannot :O

Comment: its empty..... dont know why

Comment: I've tried your code and it works, do you have any other code in the same file? It might be the cause. Also, to diagnose, try echoing out some text because it might be because the query failed, not the if statement

Comment: it's working fine. I have tested your code @StupidProgrammer  Please post your complete code and remove that action="#" no need to use.

Comment: query is good cuz wheen i remove if statement it works on page load ... its like my input hasn't clicked even if it is ....

Comment: @Nabeel it wont work for me omg :O should I try to do it with ajax? and put the update code inside different file

Comment: I updated question... how i did it

Comment: Wait, i am posting code just run and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't set any values to submit to the server.

You have to change the form like this:

```
<center>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="slj" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Seen" style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0); ">
</form>
</center>
```

A value in the submit button is just the text printed on the button. You have to set another hidden input value and that will be sent.
Also it could be heplful to change the action to `""`.

Comment: why does it work on other forms i will update  question in 1h with other forms where it works perfect.... even if i remove isset and leave just if($button) it wont work....

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, i checked the code without `hidden` input and it works.

Answer (score 0):

A submit button alone isn't enough to post a value. You should use a form field like a hidden input to post your data. I made this stupid mistake also.

```
<input type="hidden" name="slj" value="some-value">
```

Answer (score 0):

your codding is expected to work as is if there are no spelling mistakes somewhere: Although the

defining a POST element before checking if it is set, the program will see it as it is not defined  **ref:** `$jepse = $_POST['slj'];` but that should not be the main problem why your database is not updating since once you clicked the button it was then defined.

Also in your form `<form action="#"...` remove the `#`

i.e. if you are on the same page  `<form action=""...`

or

i.e. be direct  `<form action="the-php-page.php"...`

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['slj'])){


        $sql43 = "UPDATE `notifications` SET `seen`='1' WHERE `touser`='$myid' ";


        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql43)){

            echo "updated";
        }

        else
        {
            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
        }

        }

?>
<span>
<form action="" method="POST">

    <input type="submit" name="slj" value="Seen" style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0); ">

</form>
</span><br>
```

REGARDS

Answer (score 0):

```
    <center>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="slj" value="Seen" style="background: rgba(255,255,255, 0); ">
    </form>
    </center>

<?php
$jepse = $_POST['slj'];
    if(isset($jepse)){
         echo "Working fine";
        }  
    ?>
```

Let mw know whether this code return "Working fine" or not