# Button, when clicked, reloads the page instead of calling function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I was making a calculator for a game and made a button like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
```

When button is clicked, I want to run the following `myFunction()` script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var currDura, maxDura, tempMaxDura, tempDura, totDura, optDura;
var iniCost, repCost;
var smithEffi, smithCharge;
var se, sc;
var totCostTillNow, costPerBattle = 0, minCPB;
var i;
var repCount = 1;
//Assigning the values
currDura=document.getElementById("currDura_").value;
maxDura=document.getElementById("maxDura_").value;
iniCost=document.getElementById("iniCost_").value;
repCost=document.getElementById("repCost_").value;
smithEffi=document.getElementById("smithEffi_").value;
smithCharge=document.getElementById("smithCharge_").value;

se = smithEffi / 100;
sc = smithCharge / 100;
tempMaxDura = maxDura;
tempDura = currDura;
totDura = tempDura;
totCostTillNow = iniCost;
costPerBattle = totCostTillNow / totDura;
minCPB = costPerBattle;

for(i=1; i<=60; i++)
{
    totCostTillNow += (double) repCost * sc;
    tempDura = tempMaxDura * se;
    totDura += tempDura;
    costPerBattle = (double) (totCostTillNow / totDura);
    tempMaxDura -= 1;
    if ( minCPB >=  costPerBattle )
    {
        minCPB = costPerBattle;
        optDura = tempMaxDura;
    }
}
document.getElementById("result").value = eval(minCPB) + " gold at 0/"+ eval(optDura);
//alert("minimum cost per battle = "+ eval(minCPB)+ "at 0/"+ eval(optDura));
}
</script>
```

Here result is a label where I want to provide the final answer.
When I click the button, it should run the function `myFunction()` but it doesn't. Instead it refreshes the page and all the data entered is gone.
Can you help me why this is occurring?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Cost Per Battle Calculator
</title>
</head>
<style>
.smaller{
    width: 50px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bigger{
    width: 110px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button{
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 0px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #badf6f;
    padding:20px;
}
</style>



<body>



<div>
  <form>
    <!-- <label for="fname" id="fn">First Name</label> -->
    <!-- <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"> -->
    <!-- <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button> -->
     <table border="0">
        <tr>
             <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/gold.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/wood_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/ore_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/mercury_s.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/sulphur_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/crystal_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><img src="http://trial.6te.net/images/gems_S.gif"></img></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gold_" name="Gold" class="bigger">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="wood_" name="Wood" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="ore_" name="Ore" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="mercury_" name="Mercury" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="sulphur_" name="Sulphur" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="crystals_" name="Crystals" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="gems_" name="Gems" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="currDura_" name="Current Durability" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="maxDura_" name="Maximum Durability" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="repCost_" name="Repair Cost" class="bigger">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="smithEffi_" name="Smith Efficiency" class="smaller">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="smithCharge_" name="Smith Charge" class="smaller">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7">
                <label id="result"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
//Here is the above script
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your HTML? My guess is you have your button inside of a `<form>`. Clicking a button inside of a form will submit that form.

Comment: @MikeC yes the button is in a form. Shouldn't it be there? btw updated the code with html too

Comment: You shouldn't have a form unless you're planning on submitting some data to a server. Just get rid of the form wrapping your code and it should be fine.

Comment: @MikeC it has html now. So forms are used only for transferring data to a server? Can't they be used in a normal website?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using one but there's also no point. It's like bringing a swimsuit into the movie theatre. No one is going to tell you no, but you aren't exactly going to be swimming in there.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip :) But it isn't solving my problem :(

Comment: What? Yes it does. Remove the form and everything works. If you're adamant about keeping the form then add `onsubmit="return false;"` to your form. Returning `false` during a submission will prevent the submission from going through.

Comment: hmm I tried to run it that way but it isn't working :(

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? I can see a few problems occurring.

Comment: @MikeC yes I can also see errors. first one was Unexpected identifiers due to (double), I removed it. Now it is saying function myFunction() is not defined. Can you help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the button is submitting the form. To fix it you need to `return false;`.

```
onclick="myFunction(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add param `e` in your function, and the just write `e.preventDefault()`. More about [that](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp).

```
myFunction(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<button>` to some other tag like `<div>` or `<span>`. It will not look like a button, but functionally it will do what you want. You can style the div with css to look more like button if you want.

```
<center><span onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</span></center>
```

Comment: I know OP put it in their code but it's worth mentioning that [`<center>` is deprecated.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html)