# How to show each item of <li>?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a menu where your content is displayed via a modal. As part `li` is unique (has neither an `id` and nor a `class`), then `jQuery` will capture the last element declared.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu li').click(function(){
    $('.item_modal').addClass('open');
 });

 $('.modal_btn_fechar').click(function(){
   $('.item_modal').removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
html, body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: red;
}

.menu{
 position: absolute;
}

.item_modal{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: black;
 color: white;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.open{
 z-index: 999;
 transform: translateY(0%);
 transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
 <li>ITEM 1</li>
 <li>ITEM 2</li>
 <li>ITEM 3</li> 
</ul>
</div>

<div class="item_modal">
<center>
  <h1> ITEM 1 </h1> <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>

  <p>Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.<br><br>

 Eu dou dinheiro pra minha filha. Eu dou dinheiro pra ela viajar, então é... é... Já vivi muito sem dinheiro, já vivi muito com dinheiro. -Jornalista: Coloca esse dinheiro na poupança que a senhora ganha R$10 mil por mês. -Dilma: O que que é R$10 mil?<br><br>

 A população ela precisa da Zona Franca de Manaus, porque na Zona franca de Manaus, não é uma zona de exportação, é uma zona para o Brasil. Portanto ela tem um objetivo, ela evita o desmatamento, que é altamente lucravito. Derrubar arvores da natureza é muito lucrativo!<br><br>

    Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14... Por que é que<br><br> não?

 No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.<br><br>

 A única área que eu acho, que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e aí eu já aventei a hipótese de até criar um ministério. É na área de... Na área... Eu diria assim, como uma espécie de analogia com o que acontece na área agrícola.<br><br>

 Se hoje é o dia das crianças... Ontem eu disse: o dia da criança é o dia da mãe, dos pais, das professoras, mas também é o dia dos animais, sempre que você olha uma criança, há sempre uma figura oculta, que é um cachorro atrás. O que é algo muito importante!<br><br>
  </p>
</center>
</div>

<div class="item_modal">
<center>
 <h1> ITEM 2 </h1> 
 <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>

 <p>No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.<br><br>

 Eu dou dinheiro pra minha filha. Eu dou dinheiro pra ela viajar, então é... é... Já vivi muito sem dinheiro, já vivi muito com dinheiro. -Jornalista: Coloca esse dinheiro na poupança que a senhora ganha R$10 mil por mês. -Dilma: O que que é R$10 mil?<br><br>

 Se hoje é o dia das crianças... Ontem eu disse: o dia da criança é o dia da mãe, dos pais, das professoras, mas também é o dia dos animais, sempre que você olha uma criança, há sempre uma figura oculta, que é um cachorro atrás. O que é algo muito importante!<br><br>

 Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.<br><br>

 Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14... Por que é que não?<br><br>

 Primeiro eu queria cumprimentar os internautas. -Oi Internautas! Depois dizer que o meio ambiente é sem dúvida nenhuma uma ameaça ao desenvolvimento sustentável. E isso significa que é uma ameaça pro futuro do nosso planeta e dos nossos países. O desemprego beira 20%, ou seja, 1 em cada 4 portugueses.<br><br>

 Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.<br><br>
 </p>
</center>
</div>


<div class="item_modal">
<center>
 <h1> ITEM 3 </h1> 
 <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>
 
  <p>Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14... Por que é que não?<br><br>

 Eu dou dinheiro pra minha filha. Eu dou dinheiro pra ela viajar, então é... é... Já vivi muito sem dinheiro, já vivi muito com dinheiro. -Jornalista: Coloca esse dinheiro na poupança que a senhora ganha R$10 mil por mês. -Dilma: O que que é R$10 mil?<br><br>

 A única área que eu acho, que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e aí eu já aventei a hipótese de até criar um ministério. É na área de... Na área... Eu diria assim, como uma espécie de analogia com o que acontece na área agrícola.<br><br>

 A população ela precisa da Zona Franca de Manaus, porque na Zona franca de Manaus, não é uma zona de exportação, é uma zona para o Brasil. Portanto ela tem um objetivo, ela evita o desmatamento, que é altamente lucravito. Derrubar arvores da natureza é muito lucrativo!<br><br>

 No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.<br><br>
 </p>
</center>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I get each element open each menu item with its respective `div` ?

`<li>`ITEM 1`</li>` → Open a div  `<h1>` ITEM 1 `</h1>`"
`<li>`ITEM 2`</li>` → Open a div  `<h1>` ITEM 2 `</h1>`" ...

**Note:** Run the snippet in **full page mode**.

Comment: While you're at it, I'd recommend removing those `<center>` tags as they are [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) and the `<h1>` overdose will hit your SEO rankings hard...

Comment: I made the code in a hurry. It was only to exemplify. Thank you for the warning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine which **`li`** element was clicked and open the corresponding **`div`** by using:

- The [**`:nth-of-type`**](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector &
- The [**`index()`**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

**Code:**

```
$('.menu li').click(function() {
    var uid = $('.menu li').index(this) + 2;
    $('.item_modal:nth-of-type(' + uid + ')').addClass("open");
};
```

---

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6L94dxsp/).

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu li').click(function() {
    var uid = $('.menu li').index(this) + 2;
    $('.item_modal:nth-of-type(' + uid + ')').addClass("open");
  });

  $('.modal_btn_fechar').click(function() {
    $('.item_modal').removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
}
.item_modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.open {
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>ITEM 1</li>
    <li>ITEM 2</li>
    <li>ITEM 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="item_modal">
  <center>
    <h1> ITEM 1 </h1> 
    <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>
    <p>I am the text for Item 1.</p>
  </center>
</div>

<div class="item_modal">
  <center>
    <h1> ITEM 2 </h1>
    <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>
    <p>I am the text for Item 2.</p>
  </center>
</div>


<div class="item_modal">
  <center>
    <h1> ITEM 3 </h1>
    <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>
    <p>I am the text for Item 3.</p>
  </center>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I will insert other elements in the menu, in this case, I believe that the only solution is to add class by class in each <li>, correct? This code repetition is bad practice? Thanks for your response!

Comment: Insert as many elements as you want provided that the order is: **`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`** and not **`1, 2, 4, 3, 5`** etc and the code will work fine without you having to do anything else. Code repetition is almost always bad practice @Zkk :)

Comment: If for some odd reason you want the elements in a non-canonical order, you can set a **`class`** for each **`li`** and each **`div`** or use anchors to bind them.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other `.menu li`s or `.item_modal`s and their order is always kept the same, then you could use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

In the code below, the ***n***th `.menu li` will open the ***n***th `.item_modal`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menu li').click(function() {
    $('.item_modal').eq($('.menu li').index(this)).addClass('open');
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------------- changed here
 });

 $('.modal_btn_fechar').click(function(){
   $('.item_modal').removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
html, body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: red;
}

.menu{
 position: absolute;
}

.item_modal{
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: black;
 color: white;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.open{
 z-index: 999;
 transform: translateY(0%);
 transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
 <li>ITEM 1</li>
 <li>ITEM 2</li>
 <li>ITEM 3</li> 
</ul>
</div>

<div class="item_modal">
<center>
  <h1> ITEM 1 </h1> <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>

  <p>Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.<br><br>

 Eu dou dinheiro pra minha filha. Eu dou dinheiro pra ela viajar, então é... é... Já vivi muito sem dinheiro, já vivi muito com dinheiro. -Jornalista: Coloca esse dinheiro na poupança que a senhora ganha R$10 mil por mês. -Dilma: O que que é R$10 mil?<br><br>

 A população ela precisa da Zona Franca de Manaus, porque na Zona franca de Manaus, não é uma zona de exportação, é uma zona para o Brasil. Portanto ela tem um objetivo, ela evita o desmatamento, que é altamente lucravito. Derrubar arvores da natureza é muito lucrativo!<br><br>

    Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14... Por que é que<br><br> não?

 No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.<br><br>

 A única área que eu acho, que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e aí eu já aventei a hipótese de até criar um ministério. É na área de... Na área... Eu diria assim, como uma espécie de analogia com o que acontece na área agrícola.<br><br>

 Se hoje é o dia das crianças... Ontem eu disse: o dia da criança é o dia da mãe, dos pais, das professoras, mas também é o dia dos animais, sempre que você olha uma criança, há sempre uma figura oculta, que é um cachorro atrás. O que é algo muito importante!<br><br>
  </p>
</center>
</div>

<div class="item_modal">
<center>
 <h1> ITEM 2 </h1> 
 <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>

 <p>No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.<br><br>

 Eu dou dinheiro pra minha filha. Eu dou dinheiro pra ela viajar, então é... é... Já vivi muito sem dinheiro, já vivi muito com dinheiro. -Jornalista: Coloca esse dinheiro na poupança que a senhora ganha R$10 mil por mês. -Dilma: O que que é R$10 mil?<br><br>

 Se hoje é o dia das crianças... Ontem eu disse: o dia da criança é o dia da mãe, dos pais, das professoras, mas também é o dia dos animais, sempre que você olha uma criança, há sempre uma figura oculta, que é um cachorro atrás. O que é algo muito importante!<br><br>

 Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.<br><br>

 Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14... Por que é que não?<br><br>

 Primeiro eu queria cumprimentar os internautas. -Oi Internautas! Depois dizer que o meio ambiente é sem dúvida nenhuma uma ameaça ao desenvolvimento sustentável. E isso significa que é uma ameaça pro futuro do nosso planeta e dos nossos países. O desemprego beira 20%, ou seja, 1 em cada 4 portugueses.<br><br>

 Todos as descrições das pessoas são sobre a humanidade do atendimento, a pessoa pega no pulso, examina, olha com carinho. Então eu acho que vai ter outra coisa, que os médicos cubanos trouxeram pro brasil, um alto grau de humanidade.<br><br>
 </p>
</center>
</div>


<div class="item_modal">
<center>
 <h1> ITEM 3 </h1> 
 <h1 class="modal_btn_fechar"> X </h1>
 
  <p>Ai você fala o seguinte: "- Mas vocês acabaram isso?" Vou te falar: -"Não, está em andamento!" Tem obras que "vai" durar pra depois de 2010. Agora, por isso, nós já não desenhamos, não começamos a fazer projeto do que nós "podêmo fazê"? 11, 12, 13, 14... Por que é que não?<br><br>

 Eu dou dinheiro pra minha filha. Eu dou dinheiro pra ela viajar, então é... é... Já vivi muito sem dinheiro, já vivi muito com dinheiro. -Jornalista: Coloca esse dinheiro na poupança que a senhora ganha R$10 mil por mês. -Dilma: O que que é R$10 mil?<br><br>

 A única área que eu acho, que vai exigir muita atenção nossa, e aí eu já aventei a hipótese de até criar um ministério. É na área de... Na área... Eu diria assim, como uma espécie de analogia com o que acontece na área agrícola.<br><br>

 A população ela precisa da Zona Franca de Manaus, porque na Zona franca de Manaus, não é uma zona de exportação, é uma zona para o Brasil. Portanto ela tem um objetivo, ela evita o desmatamento, que é altamente lucravito. Derrubar arvores da natureza é muito lucrativo!<br><br>

 No meu xinélo da humildade eu gostaria muito de ver o Neymar e o Ganso. Por que eu acho que.... 11 entre 10 brasileiros gostariam. Você veja, eu já vi, parei de ver. Voltei a ver, e acho que o Neymar e o Ganso têm essa capacidade de fazer a gente olhar.<br><br>
 </p>
</center>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will insert other elements in the menu, in this case, I believe that the only solution is to add class by class in each <li>, correct? This code repetition is bad practice? Thanks for your response!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "add class by class in each <li>". Maybe if you clarify I can give a more specific answer. If by that you mean adding ids to each `.item_modal` and then adding some attribute on each `li` with that id as value so that you know what is the `.item_modal` for each `li`, that is not code duplication at all. Don't get me wrong, code duplication is an awful practice, but saying that is code duplication is saying that because you have to call some function by its name, you are duplicating its name throughout the code, which is just nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

With the code:

```
$('.item').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The clicked item is the one that will receive the added class. You should be able to use this to open the relevant class.