# How to vertically align a button below text of varying length using bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem placing a button below a thumbnail in bootstrap.
This image below shows three thumbnails with a button below it. The buttons are not vertically aligned because of the text that appears between the three different thumbnails and buttons are having different lengths.
[image: current display]
Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="height: 400px;">
        <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user_file/product/<?php echo $row->foto; ?>">
        <div class="caption">
            <center>
                <h3><?php echo $row->nama_prod; ?></h3>
                <strong><p>Rp.<?php echo $row->harga; ?>.-</p></strong>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/pesanan/pesan?id_product=<?php echo $row->id_product?>" class="btn btn-success"> Pesan</a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

hope this may helpful:

make **thumbnail** class as relative `position:relative;` then add `position:absolute; top:auto; bottom:0;` to `<a>` tag

Comment: yes its make the button in the same position, but out of the thumbnail box and little bit move to the right..

Comment: add left:0; right:0 to the button to make it center, then add some px in the left (eg: left:10px;) that you need

Answer (score 1):

Keep your image and caption in one row, and the link button in other row, like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
  <div class="thumbnail" style="height: 400px;">
    <div class="row">
      <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user_file/product/<?php echo $row->foto; ?>">
      <div class="caption" style="height: 140px;">
          <h3><?php echo $row->nama_prod; ?></h3>
          <strong><p>Rp.<?php echo $row->harga; ?>.-</p></strong>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/pesanan/pesan?id_product=<?php echo $row->id_product?>" class="btn btn-success"> Pesan</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set the "text-center" property to the alignment inside of the column. And the div class "caption" should have a height style.

Answer (score 0):

One way will be to use two rows like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="height: 400px;">
            <img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user_file/product/<?php echo $row->foto; ?>">
            <div class="caption">
                <center>
                    <h3><?php echo $row->nama_prod; ?></h3>
                    <strong><p>Rp.<?php echo $row->harga; ?>.-</p></strong>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/pesanan/pesan?id_product=<?php echo $row->id_product?>" class="btn btn-success"> Pesan</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
```

P.S:`center` tag is deprecated. Do not use it. [Why is the <center> tag deprecated in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html)