# i want to move my button to center of that line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" >
<span>Upload Shows</span>
<input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

## this my div of the button field and below is the css script

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

## i want to move my button to center of that line currently it appears at the left side of the page

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align: center` in `.fileUpload`. So you can try the code below:

```
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use**

```
.fileUpload { 
  text-align:center;
 }
```

**Try this code**

```css
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
 
    text-align:center;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary" >
<span>Upload Shows</span>
<input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `text-align: center;` in fileUpload class.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you code in a `div` go through with my code for better understanding.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/145/)

HTML Code-

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
  <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Upload Shows</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code-

```
.fileUpload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fileUpload input.upload {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this depending on your page layout and the kinda bootstrapping you're using.

- you may create a separate div container for the button and center the container using `margin:0 auto;`
- or [cssdeck.com](http://cssdeck.com/labs/custom-css-file-upload-form-control) here is one of the best ways

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the `center` tag.

```
<center><input type="file" class="upload" /></center>
```

OR use css `text-align` property

```
.fileUpload { 
  text-align:center;
 }
```

Comment: Center tag is deprecated and should not be used. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1798893/7108481)

Comment: Thats why i added the css text-align property.