# display image jupyter notebook aligned centre

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using the following code to insert an image in Jupyter notebook which is compatible with html conversion:

```
from IPython.display import Image

Image(filename="picture.jpg")
```

This works nicely except the fact that it is left aligned and I need it centre/middle aligned.
Is there any method that I can set it to be aligned correctly?

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```html
<center><img src="picture.jpg"/></center>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can set the cell as `markdown` and use this content:

```
<img src="picture.jpg" width="240" height="240" align="center"/>
```

Then run it.

Edit1

Alternatively, you can use a `code` cell with this code:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
html1 = '<img src="picture.jpg" width="240" height="240" align="center"/>'
HTML(html1)
```

Comment: I started using this but when converted to html the picture is not shown thats why I switched to code and using Image.

Comment: @pouya you should add that to your question, so all your requirements are clearly stated.

Comment: sorry for being unclear, I just stated to be compatible with html conversion

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax Thanks for the feedback. Please try again with the new method I just added.

Comment: @swatchai using R, will have to think how to get IPython magic in there

Comment: It works for the notebook, but if you convert the notebook to slides using nbconvert it seems to lose the centering.

Answer (score 6):

Many browsers (Chrome, Firefox) are only supporting HTML 5, so this syntax no longer works, even within the notebook itself.

```
<img src="picture.jpg" align="center"/>
```

because `align="center"` has been deprecated. Now you should use CSS style properties and the various margin definitions.

```
<img src="picture.jpg" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto"/>
```

or

```
<img src="picture.jpg" style="margin:auto"/>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) for more discussion around this. This makes it look properly centered while being displayed in your Notebook. But frustratingly doesn't work (still left justified) when you export your notebook to HTML. Inspecting the HTML that is generated you find that the `<img>` is embedded in a `<p>` element and this throws the whole thing off. So you have to add an additional `display=block` property, making the whole thing

```
<img src="picture.jpg" style="display=block; margin:auto"/>
```

This will center the image in your notebook, exported HTML, and exported Markdown files. Thanks to [these guys](https://themetry.com/horizontal-centering/) for the tip on the `display=block bit`.

To get a centered bit of text underneath the image (like a figure title) I throw in a

```
<p style="text-align: center">
    <b>Figure N. My Cool Figure</b>
</p>
```

afterwards. The whole setup is then

```
<img src="picture.jpg" style="display=block; margin:auto"/>
<p style="text-align: center">
    <b>Figure N. My Cool Figure</b>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround. i'm using the table syntax on a markdown cell to create a one column table.
tables are always aligned in the middle...
add your image and use | after it, and - below it. like this:

```
![Stacklogo](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png) |
-
```