# Python Jupyter Notebook: Center Align an Image Using Code

Tags: python, image, file, jupyter-notebook

How do I center align an image file that I added to Jupyter Notebook?  Right now it's left align.  Note: I do not want to use markdown.  I want to import the image using code.

Here's my code:

```
from IPython.display import Image 
Image(filename='C:\\Users\\LinAlg_Python_Prep\\Capture0.PNG')
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing stops you from importing the image in code and then using markdown to display it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439874/display-image-jupyter-notebook-aligned-centre

Comment: I tried that already ... it doesn't render the image at all.

Comment: We cannot help debug "that" without any actual code sample