# The html code did not center my image in jupyter notebook

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook

I tried to center both the image and caption inside my jupyter notebook, but it did not work. Here is a reproducible result. Please note I need to render it in Jupyter Notebook **without css files**.

```html
<figure>
    <img src='https://storage.googleapis.com/reighns/reighns_ml_projects/docs/linear_algebra/linear_algebra_theory_intuition_code_chap2_fig_2.3.svg' width="33%" align="center"/>
    <figcaption align = "center"><b>Fig 2.3; By me G.</b></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Workaround from comments:

```html
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/reighns/reighns_ml_projects/docs/linear_algebra/linear_algebra_theory_intuition_code_chap2_fig_2.3.svg" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display image jupyter notebook aligned centre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439874/display-image-jupyter-notebook-aligned-centre)

Comment: Yes it does, now I edited the qn to include the answer. But will like to know if I want to put 2 image side by side centered like this.