# Window.print not print all pages in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have 13 page long transaction data. Show in tabular format in html page. If I try to print this data on Mozilla it's working fine, but If I try on Chrome only 7 to 8 pages are printed. Remaining are not printed. All Data load by Ajax

```
<center id="printButton">
    <a href="javascript:window.print();"><img src="print.gif" /></a>
</center>
```

Comment: You are using a deprecated tag (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html)

Comment: My que for window.print() not for center tag

Comment: You can view the print output on the console by rendering as print. Then inspect your pages.

Comment: You need to provide more details because your problem cannot be reproduced.