# How do I center a <form> in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-position, centering

I've been trying to center my contact form for a couple of hours now, however it won't move from the left of the page. I made a form similar to this one on another project and pretty much used the same CSS with just slight alterations in font and color, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. Can y'all take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
CSS
.contact .container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.contact form {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.contact input:not([type=checkbox]),
.contact .checkbox-container,
.contact button {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 2em;
}

.contact input:not([type=checkbox]),
.contact button {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 2em;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
    background-color: rgb(170, 193, 221);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: rgb(170, 193, 221);
}

.contact button {
    width: 10%
    text-indent: 0;
    color: white;
}

HTML

<body class="contact">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>What's Buzzin'?</h1>
    <p>Love bees? Are you a beekeeper? Have facts or images that you want on the site? Contact us!</p>
    <form action="#" method="#">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="message" placeholder="Message">
        <div class="checkbox-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" checked>
        <label for="newletter">Receive Bee Business!</label>
    </div>
        <button type="submit">Buzz!</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's working on my side.

Comment: That is very odd. I will try to separate it from the rest of the code and try it again on my side.

Comment: Still not working on FF and IE for me, did you add anything to the code I gave or did you run it as is? The only bits I left out were the font sizes, font color, and background color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `<center>` tag to horizontally align the content.

```css
.contact .container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.contact form {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.contact input:not([type=checkbox]),
.contact .checkbox-container,
.contact button {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 2em;
}

.contact input:not([type=checkbox]),
.contact button {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 2em;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
    background-color: rgb(170, 193, 221);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: rgb(170, 193, 221);
}

.contact button {
    width: 10%
    text-indent: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="contact">
    <div class="container">
    <center>
    <h1>What's Buzzin'?</h1>
    <p>Love bees? Are you a beekeeper? Have facts or images that you want on the site? Contact us!</p>
    <form action="#" method="#">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="message" placeholder="Message">
        <div class="checkbox-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" checked>
        <label for="newletter">Receive Bee Business!</label>
    </div>
        <button type="submit">Buzz!</button>
    </form>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: <center> is obsolete in 2022  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want. The form is aligned to the centre.

```css
.contact .container {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.contact form {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.contact input:not([type=checkbox])，
.contact .checkbox-container
{
  background-color: #3CBC8D;
  color: white;
}

.contact input:not([type=checkbox]),
.contact .checkbox-container
{
    display: block;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 2em;
}

.contact button {
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 2em;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
    background-color: rgb(170, 193, 221);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline-block;
}

.contact input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: rgb(170, 193, 221);
}

.contact button {
    width: 10%
    text-indent: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>What's Buzzin'?</h1>
        <p>Love bees? Are you a beekeeper? Have facts or images that you want on the site? Contact us!</p>
        <form action="#" method="#">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="message" placeholder="Message">            
            <div class="checkbox-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter" checked>
                    <label for="newletter">Receive Bee Business!</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Buzz!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```