# How to bring centre alignment in web page using html?

Tags: html, css

In html, what can we write in the code to bring the content of my web page in the center ?? I have tried to write the code within {center} tag and {/center} but it's not working. so any other alternatives ??

I tried to bring centre alignment but it didn't happen.

Comment: u can try to use CSS

Comment: See [<center>: The Centered Text element - Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) (MDN).

Comment: By `{center}` do you mean `<center>`? Instead of mangling your code, try wrapping it with backticks (`\``) to render it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use the **CSS text-align property**. You can apply this property to various HTML elements like ,

, or the entire body element to center its content.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Centered Content</title>
  <style>
    p {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>This paragraph is centered horizontally on the webpage.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For more complex layouts where you want to center both horizontally and vertically, you can explore using CSS properties like **margin: 0 auto**; or combining **text-align** with other positioning properties.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's technically still part of HTML, the `<center>` tag was [deprecated in HTML 4.01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html) to emphasize that CSS stylesheets are the new home for all style and formatting parameters. That was back in 1999.

These days, you should create a [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) in CSS, then set the attributes you need for a specific effect.

Very general example:

```
.centerThisClass {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center content in webpage only via HTML is by using `center` tag.

```html
<center>
<h2>Hello world</h2>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="200px square image by picsum" width="200" height="200">
</center>
```

However it is `deprecated` and is recommend to use CSS instead.

- Centering content within the `div`.

  ```html
  <div style = "text-align: center;">
     <h2>Inside div</h2>
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="200px square image by picsum" width="200" height="200">
  </div>
  ```
- Centering `div` itself and it's content

  ```html
    <div style = "width:50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
      <h2>Inside div</h2>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="200px square image by picsum" width="200" height="200">
  </div>
  ```